# count an non existing array with php 8

Tags: php

I all!

I have this for loop, which works in php 7 without problems:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
   echo "Hello World";
}
```

No "Hello World" will be shown, because the $myArray does not exist / was not define

Since PHP 8 I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable .. on line ..
```

I can fix it with adding `if (is_countable($myArray))` at first.
But I why it worked with php without this "check"?
Is this normal since php 8? Can I fix it with one line like before?

Comment: PHP 8 has turned lots of things that used to be warnings into fatal errors.

Comment: Code like this that doesn't check whether the variable is set first is considered buggy.

Comment: `$myArray does not exist / was not define` that will throw an notice/warning in php7 as well.

Comment: You can use `??` to have a fallback to the `myArray`: `count($myArray ?? [])`

Comment: You shouldn't do `count()` in a loop criteria. It will need to be calculated for every iteration.